# Convert from GMT 'twitter' format to UTC using Unix

Tags: r, unix, date-format, date-conversion

I have some Twitter data I got through their GET search. The dates have the following GMT format.

```
Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:43 +0000  
Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:43 +0000  
Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:40 +0000  
Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:39 +0000  
Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:36 +0000  
Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:32 +0000  
Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:28 +0000  
Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:27 +0000  
Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:28 +0000  
Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:27 +0000  
Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:18 +0000
```

Any idea how could I convert them to UTC format? `Unix` and/or `R` solutions would be preferable.

Update: By UTC, I mean UTC timestamp in seconds. For example: 1318394558.

Comment: Would you be able to supply an example of the UTC format you describe?

Comment: Those times are also in UTC; UTC is perpetually at zero time zone offset, as are those values because of the `+0000` time zone suffix.  If you want a different format, you should explain what you think of as the UTC format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `date` tool, perhaps something like:

```
date -f file.txt "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"
```

Results:

```
2012-07-19 11:32:43 EST
2012-07-19 11:32:43 EST
2012-07-19 11:32:40 EST
2012-07-19 11:32:39 EST
2012-07-19 11:32:36 EST
2012-07-19 11:32:32 EST
2012-07-19 11:32:28 EST
2012-07-19 11:32:27 EST
2012-07-19 11:32:28 EST
2012-07-19 11:32:27 EST
2012-07-19 11:32:18 EST
```

Alternatively, something like:

```
date -f file.txt "+%F %T"
```

Gives:

```
2012-07-19 11:32:43
2012-07-19 11:32:43
2012-07-19 11:32:40
2012-07-19 11:32:39
2012-07-19 11:32:36
2012-07-19 11:32:32
2012-07-19 11:32:28
2012-07-19 11:32:27
2012-07-19 11:32:28
2012-07-19 11:32:27
2012-07-19 11:32:18
```

**EDIT:**

```
date -f file.txt -u +%s
```

Results:

```
1342661563
1342661563
1342661560
1342661559
1342661556
1342661552
1342661548
1342661547
1342661548
1342661547
1342661538
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you, By UTC, I mean UTC timestamp in seconds. For example: 1318394558

Answer (score 3):

In `R`,

```
dat <- c("Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:43 +0000",
         "Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:43 +0000",
         "Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:40 +0000",
         "Thu, 19 Jul 2012 01:32:39 +0000")

as.POSIXct(dat, format="%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
#[1] "2012-07-18 20:32:43 CDT" "2012-07-18 20:32:43 CDT" "2012-07-18 20:32:40 CDT" "2012-07-18 20:32:39 CDT"
```

See `?strptime`

Or, if you want numeric

```
as.numeric(as.POSIXct(dat, format="%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"))
[1] 1342661563 1342661563 1342661560 1342661559
```

Comment: Thank you! This result is very helpful as well. I wish I could select 2 answers..